# Should I get a notification on any new answer/comment under my question?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I cannot see any kind of notification either in my global inbox nor responses tab on this comment [How to add new element to Varargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321784/how-to-add-new-element-to-varargs#comment14903644_11321901) under my own question.

**1)** Should I get notification on that comment?

**2)** Should I get notification on any comment under my question. That includes comments under both the question itself and any answer?

### Update

I have just found out that I copied in my question wrong comment. I meant comment that doesn't have @ ping. I thought that all comments under my question are going to be notified.
[How to add new element to Varargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321784/how-to-add-new-element-to-varargs#comment14915308_11321820)

Comment: I'm seeing [that comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321784/how-to-add-new-element-to-varargs#comment14903644_11321901) in both your inbox and on your Stack Overflow user profile's responses tab; can you still not see it?

Comment: @Jarrod: yes, you're right. See my update. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You should have gotten a notification there *because he @pinged you*.
2. No. You get notifications of comments on the question directly, any that @ping you, and if you are the only commenter on an answer where its poster posts a comment (less well known auto-ping).

Comment: Is there anyway to get a ping for *any* comment for an question/answer that you've commented on, even without a @ping?

Comment: No. Sorry, but there are no optional pings, either you get it or you don't.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you get notified of **as the question owner**:

- any comments on your question
- any answers to your question
- any comments on a self-answer to your question

For the most part, you are notified of everything on your question *except* **comments on other people's answers**. You will only be notified of comments on other people's answers to your question when …

- you have already commented on that particular answer, and someone mentions you in a later comment by @name

Generally when someone makes a comment on an answer, they are not talking to you, the question owner. They are talking to the person who posted that answer.

Comment: So generally if I want to talk to someone I use `@`. Thank you

Comment: No. Notice that I did not mention your name here -- why did this work? Ask yourself, who else could I be talking to? If you post a comment on a question or answer, the person who wrote that question or answer is always notified. Click the help link under the [Add Comment] button.